# ORA-04091 mutating table error when calling a function from a procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a task:

> Write a procedure to update salary (salary * % of increment) in emp table based on grade. Use function to get increment

This is my procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
  PROCEDURE sal_incre
  IS
    CURSOR c_cur
    IS
      SELECT * FROM emp_task;
  BEGIN
    UPDATE emp_task SET sal = sal + sal_incr(grade_id);
    FOR rec IN c_cur
    LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line(rec.empno||','||rec.ename||','||rec.sal);
    END LOOP;
  END;
```

This is my function code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
  FUNCTION sal_incr(
      p_grade NUMBER)
    RETURN
  IS
    v_inc NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT raise_percent
    INTO v_inc
    FROM sal_inc
    WHERE grade_id IN
      (SELECT grade_id FROM emp_task WHERE grade_id = p_grade
      );
    RETURN v_inc;
    COMMIT;
  END;
```

When I call the procedure I'm getting:

```
ORA-04091: table SCOTT.EMP_TASK is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.SAL_INCR", line 8
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.SAL_INCRE", line 6
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the complete trigger code.

Comment: Please show the *function* code... and the table DDL.

Comment: ---This is my function code:

create or replace
function sal_incr
(
p_grade number)
return number
is
v_inc number;
begin
select raise_percent into v_inc from sal_inc where grade_id in (select grade_id from emp_task where grade_id = p_grade);
return v_inc;
commit;
end;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is referring to the same table you're using in the procedure at the point you *call* that function, which is what causes this error. You're updating and querying it at the same time, in a way that could cause indeterminate (or confusing) results, even though you aren't querying the column you're updating. Oracle is protecting you from yourself here.

In your function you're doing:

```
SELECT raise_percent 
INTO v_inc 
FROM sal_inc 
WHERE grade_id IN 
(SELECT grade_id FROM emp_task WHERE grade_id = p_grade 
);
```

There is no need to look at the `emp_task` table here. Unless you've been passed an nonexistent value (which can't happen from your procedure) the subquery can only return the original `p_grade` argument value, so this is the same as:

```
SELECT raise_percent 
INTO v_inc 
FROM sal_inc 
WHERE grade_id = p_grade;
```

If you do that the function no longer refers to `emp_task`, so it won't throw the mutating trigger/function error when it's called as part of an update.

And your function should not be issuing a `COMMIT` - let the calling procedure, or preferably the session that calls the procedure, decide whether the who transaction should be committed or rolled back.

Also, from the title and column name it looks like `raise_percent` is a percentage, so you need to use that to find the value to multiply by - you shouldn't *add* that percentage figure. If that gives you a value of 2 for a 2% raise, for example, you need to either do this in your procedure:

```
UPDATE emp_task SET sal = sal * (1 + (sal_incr(grade_id)/100));
```

Or more neatly have your function return `1 + (raise_percent/100)` and do:

```
UPDATE emp_task SET sal = sal * sal_incr(grade_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the procedure like this:

```
create or replace
  procedure sal_incre
  is
    cursor c_cur is
      select distinct e.grade_id,e.ename,e.sal from sal_inc s
      join emp_task e on e.grade_id = s.grade_id order by e.ename ;
    v_incr number;
  begin
    for f_cur in c_cur
    loop
      v_incr := sal_incr(f_cur.grade_id);
      update emp_task set sal = sal + v_incr;
      dbms_output.put_line('Emp Name : '||f_cur.ename||','
        ||' Sal:'||f_cur.sal||','||' Grade: '||f_cur.grade_id);
    end loop;
  end;
```

Comment: This is avoiding the error by doing single-row updates, which is less efficient. The function doesn't need to refer to the `emp_task` table.